# Plural forms with Java java.util.ResourceBundle

Tags: java, internationalization, j2objc

I use`java.util.ResourceBundle` for i18n like this:

```
try {
  resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Messages", locale);
} catch (MissingResourceException ex) {
  logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
}

String localizedString = resourceBundle.getString("key");
```

I want to create the plural forms are well. Like:

```
one object
two objects
```

**How can I define plural forms of localized Strings?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how Java handles plural forms:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/choiceFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

A ResourceBundle doesn't deal with pluralization. It just allows getting values associated with keys, based on a locale.

To have pluralized translations, use different keys, or use a [ChoiceFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/ChoiceFormat.html#ChoiceFormat%28java.lang.String%29). Note that [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) can use a ChoiceFormat by specifying it in its pattern.